# running a script using WScript.Shell on a network location

Tags: vbscript

I have a script which is on a network path and when I use the below code to run it I get an error the system cannot find the file specified.Do I need to do something for this to work in a network location.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "\\\host\aid\prog\Files.vbs" & Trim(arglist), 0, True
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to assume that VBS treats the '\' as a special character like many other scripting languages do. Try  "\\\\host\\aid\\prog\\Files.vbs"  or  "//host/aid/prog/Files.vbs"

Comment: Q: Is the string ""\\host\aid\prog\Files.vbs my args list" valid for "CreateObject("SCript.Shell").Run"?  Assuming the share is valid and the .vbs file exists... My guess is that maybe you need to separate the .vbs filename from "argslist".  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You trim leading an trailing spaces from your argument list and then concatenate the result to the script path. Unless your argument list is an empty string this will create a non-existing filename. Example:

```
arglist = "/foo"
WScript.Echo "\\host\aid\prog\Files.vbs" & Trim(arglist)
```

produces the following output:

```
\\host\aid\prog\Files.vbs/foo
```

To make your code work you need to add a space between script path and arguments:

```
...
filename = "\\host\aid\prog\Files.vbs"
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run filename & " " & Trim(arglist), 0, True
```

Comment: Ur a champ man in VBScript ..U answer so many of my questions..Thank u so much